# JSP WebServlet urlPatterns mapping with subpaths

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

We are creating a JSP web application for a school project in Netbeans and are trying to figure out how to map the url patterns.

In the servlet, we currently map the urlPattern like this

```
@WebServlet(name = "ViewActivities", urlPatterns = {"/view_activities"})
```

But we would like the urlPattern to include an extended path like this

```
@WebServlet(name = "ViewActivities", urlPatterns = {"/partner/view_activities"})
```

So that we can separate the servlets into sections, that feels more correct then using

```
@WebServlet(name = "ViewActivities", urlPatterns = {"/partner_view_activities"})
```

We are facing a similar problem with the .jsp pages in the subfolders of the web pages folder.

We have tried to save them in a subfolder called partner and then call them like this

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/partner/view_activities.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Which only results in 404 errors

So far we haven't found any articles that explains how to do this, so is it even possible? or is there a completely different approach to this problem?

Comment: Have you double checked spelling, including case sensitivity?

Comment: Have copy pasted the exact same sentence and tried with /sub/path/ sub/path/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an absolute path like /partner/view_activities.jsp, you should use the request dispatcher offered by the ServletContext

contextObj.getRequestDispatcher("/partner/view_activities.jsp").forward(request, response);

Edit

The request dispatcher offered by the request object is relative to the request path. For example if your Servlet was accessed using say "/partner" and you have the jsps stored in a folder called 'partner', then you would use

request.getRequestDispatcher("view_activities.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: That fixes the problem with subfolders in the Web Pages folder

Comment: What other problems do you have ?

Comment: Actually that fixes the problem I had with the servlet url pattern aswell.